# Installing MCollective on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, mcollective

I have tried installing MCollective on the latest version of Ubuntu, and out of the box, it does not seem to be working. I am curious what I have missed, and where the correct place to file a bug is, assuming it is a bug.

Steps so far:

```
$ apt-get install mcollective-middleware mcollective mcollective-client
$ mc-find-hosts 
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/mcollective.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/mcollective.rb:1
    from /usr/sbin/mc-find-hosts:3:in `require'
    from /usr/sbin/mc-find-hosts:3
```

At this point, it looks like the `rubygems` package should have been listed as a dependency. OK, so lets install that:

```
$ apt-get install rubygems
$ mc-find-hosts
$
```

Now it is just failing silently after a short delay.

Anyone experienced this or know of a way to solved it?

Comment: try putting sudo infront maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the "silence", I restarted the mcollective service and things are now working as expected.

It looks like the package dependencies are a little messed up on Ubuntu 11.10 oneiric.

I have submitted a bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mcollective/+bug/884908